# Join two tables without a common column in Oracle

Tags: oracle, join

I have two tables -

Employee :

```
EmployeeNo | EmployeeName | EmployeeDesignation | CompanyID 
12345      | ABC          | Doctor              | 3434
4545       | XYZ          | Engineer            | 3434
```

Department :

```
DepartmentNo | EmployeeNo | Location
0808         | 12345      | Loc1
0989         | 12345      | Loc2
```

I want to print the employee details along with the count of location in the department table. The output should like this -

```
EmployeeNo| EmployeeName| EmployeeDesignation| Count(Location)
12345     | ABC         | Doctor             | 2
4545      | XYZ         | Engineer           |
```

When I am using inner join, it is displaying the details of the employeeId `12345` and not of `4545`. I know it is so because there is no data for `4545` in the corresponding EmployeeNo column of the Department Table. I know we can use cross join for combining tables without common column but it is giving me a garbage number in the count column.

My query with inner join -

```
select Employee.EmployeeNo, Employee.EmployeeName, Employee.EmployeeDesignation, count(Department.Location) as count
from Employee inner join Department on
Employee.EmployeeNo = Department.EmployeeNo
where Employee.CompanyID like '3434'
group by Employee.EmployeeNo, Employee.EmployeeName, Employee.EmployeeDesignation
```

My query with Cross join

```
select Employee.EmployeeNo, Employee.EmployeeName, Employee.EmployeeDesignation, count(Department.Location) as count
from Employee, Department
where Employee.CompanyID like '3434'
group by Employee.EmployeeNo, Employee.EmployeeName, Employee.EmployeeDesignation
```

Comment: Your data model is flawed.  The DEPARTMENT table should contain only information about departments. It should not have employee info - like employee number.  The employee table should have a column indicating the dept_id of the dept the employee is assigned to.  And if that is a many to many relationship (an employee can be assigned to multiple departments   (?!?!?!)  then you'd need a third, 'junction' table to join the employees to the departments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT e.EmployeeNo,
       e.EmployeeName,
       e.EmployeeDesignation,
       COUNT(d.Location) as count
FROM   Employee e
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Department d
       ON (e.EmployeeNo = d.EmployeeNo)
WHERE  e.CompanyID like '3434'
GROUP BY
       e.EmployeeNo,
       e.EmployeeName,
       e.EmployeeDesignation
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Employee (
  EmployeeNo PRIMARY KEY,
  EmployeeName,
  EmployeeDesignation,
  CompanyID
) AS
SELECT 12345, 'ABC', 'Doctor',   3434 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4545,  'XYZ', 'Engineer', 3434 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Department (
  DepartmentNo PRIMARY KEY,
  EmployeeNo,
  Location
) AS
SELECT '0808', 12345, 'Loc1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0989', 12345, 'Loc2' FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE Department ADD CONSTRAINT department__employeeno__fk
  FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeNo) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeNo);
```

Outputs:

> | EMPLOYEENO | EMPLOYEENAME | EMPLOYEEDESIGNATION | COUNT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 4545 | XYZ | Engineer | 0 |
> | 12345 | ABC | Doctor | 2 |

---

Additionally, if `EmployeeNo` is the primary key then you do not need to include the non-primary key columns in the `GROUP BY` clause and can aggregate to get those columns:

```sql
SELECT e.EmployeeNo,
       MAX(e.EmployeeName) AS EmployeeName,
       MAX(e.EmployeeDesignation) AS EmployeeDesignation,
       COUNT(d.Location) as count
FROM   Employee e
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Department d
       ON (e.EmployeeNo = d.EmployeeNo)
WHERE  e.CompanyID like '3434'
GROUP BY
       e.EmployeeNo
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fb7a2dd2a3f3848ecb89e73bda7da0db)*